# Job link 404s from search page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

[This job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/122553/sr-engineer-prodt-dev-engineering-comcast?a=F6ee4ay6gkU&so=p&offset=1&location=Reston%2C%20VA&range=20&sort=p) with this link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/122553/sr-engineer-prodt-dev-engineering-comcast?a=F6ee4ay6gkU&so=p&offset=1&location=Reston%2C%20VA&range=20&sort=p
```

404s on the search page:

[image]

Also happening to other Comcast jobs:

> https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/122565/software-engineer-delivery-engineering-team-comcast
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/122563/sr-designer-user-experience-comcast

Both links were found through the [StackDevJobs](https://twitter.com/StackDevJobs) twitter account.

Comment: Investigating now!

Comment: Well, found the issue, just working out how to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was a tough one to fix :/

LINQ to SQL betrayed us during a data model refactor by filtering incorrectly despite the query saying otherwise. We've removed a bunch of what turned out to be obsolete code and simplified things a bit which means this can no longer happen.

I just pushed that fix to production. Thanks for the report!